# How get an 'alt' text tag on a background image sprite

Tags: html, css, accessibility, css-sprites

I have a button (that opens a new browser window) so I've put alternate_text & Title tags - so the browser displays pop-up text when hovered over - that notifies the user that a NEW window will open.

```
<img class="mp3PlayBtn alt="Mp3 player opens in popup window" title="Mp3 player opens in popup window" src="https://cdn.shopify.com......."  />
```

This works fine, but I now want to make the image change when hovered/clicked.
Normally I would use a background sprite image (see CSS below)

```
.mp3PlayBtn {
background-image:url('https://cdn.shopify.com......Mp3PlayButton.png');     background-repeat: no-repeat;   
height: 30px; width:40px;
background-position: 0px 0px; 
} 
.mp3PlayBtn:hover  {background-position: 0px -28px;} 
.mp3PlayBtn:active {background-position: 0px -58px;}
```

But as it's a background image, it will not show pop-up text.

How can I keep the pop-up text AND use a sprite to change the image?
Or must a forgo the sprite?

Answer (score 4):

The text when hovering isn't defined by the "alt" attribute, but by the "title" attribute, so you can use that on a regular `div` which has a background image, and it also works with sprites as shown below:

```css
.x {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x100/fa0);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.x:hover {
  background-position: 100px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x" title="Here I am"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks ... and a very clear explanation.
PS - Alt was retained as I have to support old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In term of accessibility, the `title` attribute is rarely used by assistive technologies like screenreaders.

So you can use the `title` attribute as it will help showing a tooltip on mouse events, but you have to use conjointly the `aria-label` attribute.

```
<button id="mp3PlayBtn"
       aria-label="Mp3 player opens in popup window"
       title="Mp3 player opens in popup window"></button>
```

Of course, you have to use a `button` element in order to handle native `tabindex` value and correct aria role definition.